# Multiplication across multiple Rows Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am somewhat of a noob when it comes to VBA programming. I have two basic multiplication formulas that I want applied to all rows in a table. How do I dynamically code this so that it copies down for each row in a table (where the number of rows may change every time)? Instead of just copying this code sequentially and incrementally row by row....

```
Dim FxRate As Variant

FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")

Range("O2").Select
  ActiveCell.Value = Range("N2") * Range("L2")

Range("P2").Select
  ActiveCell.Value = Range("O2") / FxRate
```

Comment: Use a formula? `Range("O2:O100").Formula = "=N2*L2"`, changing the `100` to your last row as needed.

Comment: @BigBen don't you mean a `lastrow` variable?

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate and Write to Cells

- This is an intermediate solution in five versions which all do the same. They are sorted by readability descending (Some might consider the second solution most readable, but the first is certainly most maintainable.). The first is showing how when using constants you can quickly find e.g. `Res2` (the second result column) and change it e.g. to `Z` (Imagine there are hundreds of lines.).
- In a nutshell, the code first opens an `InputBox` where the user is expected to enter a numeric value (`FxRate`). Then it calculates the Last Row (the row of the last non-blank cell) in column `N`. Then it loops through rows from `FirstRow` to `LastRow` and for each row writes the product of the value in columns `N` and `L` to column `O` and then divides the (new) value in column `O` with the `FxRate` and writes the result of the division to column `P`. Finally, using a `MsgBox`, it informs the user that it has finished (almost).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Change the name of the procedure ("spreadData") to something more meaningful.
Sub spreadData()

    ' Constants
    ' Use common sense to decide which column to use to calculate the last row.
    Const LastRowCol As Variant = "N" ' e.g. 1 or "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    ' Find/Replace the following 4 constants names with descriptive ones
    ' like you did with "FxRate".
    Const Col1 As Variant = "N"
    Const Col2 As Variant = "L"
    Const Res1 As Variant = "O"
    Const Res2 As Variant = "P"
    
    ' Let the user input a value.
    Dim FxRate As Variant
    FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")
    
    ' Calculate the Last Row containing data in Last Row Column.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Calculate and write the results to cells.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        Cells(i, Res1).Value = Cells(i, Col1).Value * Cells(i, Col2).Value
        Cells(i, Res2).Value = Cells(i, Res1).Value / FxRate
    Next i

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data written.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Sub spreadDataNoConstants()
    
    ' Let the user input a value.
    Dim FxRate As Variant
    FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")
    
    ' Calculate the Last Row containing data in Last Row Column.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Calculate and write the results to cells.
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(i, "O").Value = Cells(i, "N").Value * Cells(i, "L").Value
        Cells(i, "P").Value = Cells(i, "O").Value / FxRate
    Next i

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data written.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Sub spreadDataNoComments()
    
    Dim FxRate As Variant
    FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(i, "O").Value = Cells(i, "N").Value * Cells(i, "L").Value
        Cells(i, "P").Value = Cells(i, "O").Value / FxRate
    Next i

    MsgBox "Data written.", vbInformation, "Success"

End Sub

Sub spreadDataNoSections()
    Dim FxRate As Variant
    FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(i, "O").Value = Cells(i, "N").Value * Cells(i, "L").Value
        Cells(i, "P").Value = Cells(i, "O").Value / FxRate
    Next i
    MsgBox "Data written.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Sub spreadDataNoIndentation()
Dim FxRate As Variant
FxRate = InputBox("Input FX Rate:")
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To LastRow
Cells(i, "O").Value = Cells(i, "N").Value * Cells(i, "L").Value
Cells(i, "P").Value = Cells(i, "O").Value / FxRate
Next i
MsgBox "Data written.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. I want to round the resulting product to two decimals. What would the code like like for that?